# Facebook Messenger - bubble-popup

Tags: java, android, facebook, layout, bubble-popup

How to make a bubble-popup?

It's about showing the other applications, and transparency.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRdaZ.jpg

(Sorry for my language, I write with a translator.)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot mark this as a duplicate, but there are some other questions here about this:

[How to make a Facebook Messenger-like notification like this in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015971/how-to-make-facebook-messenger-like-notification-like-this-in-android)

[How to draw a view on top of everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264650/android-how-to-draw-view-over-top-of-everything)

Everything is based on:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW