# How to make a Facebook Messenger-like notification like this in Android

Tags: android

I want to implement notifications like the one in the following image.

Notification appears any time. I think it's of course a background service waiting for new messages from the server then shows this. What I think this is an activity implemented as dialog with this custom UI. Am I correct? And is it a normal startActivity method from the service? And how do I do the transition animation to make it appears slowly from left to right with zooming when show up?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/henrychuangtw/Android-ChatHead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What APIs in Android is Facebook using to create Chat Heads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-in-android-is-facebook-using-to-create-chat-heads)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Check out this link http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics. He provides information about how to add them on your screen.

The trick is to add a `View` to the `WindowManager` like following code

```
private WindowManager windowManager;
private ImageView chatHead;

public void addView()
{
  windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

  chatHead = new ImageView(this);
  chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_head);

  WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

  params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
  params.x = 0;
  params.y = 100;

  windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
}
```

Don't forget to add the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>`

Comment: can you tell me how can i add a layout (near the circle) just as facebook does when we click on the circular notification.

Comment: You should have provided credit to the original answer on this subject, where you copied the exact same code from.

Comment: @JustinMitchell We have the same code because we used the same source. I did not copy his answer.

Comment: @Amnesh Goel I noticed that you didn't accept my edited changes, yet added your own. It has several spelling mistakes, could you please revert to the changes that I added.