# Displaying notifications even when screen is locked

Tags: android, notifications, lockscreen

I want to display notification even when the screen is locked.
The pre-requisites are :
1.the notification should be displayed when the application is opened(this part I've covered).
2.there is a timer which will run in the background and on locking the screen, while app is running, the timer will start. After certain duration the notification will appear on the screen.
Can please anyone help me with this?

Comment: You want to show something on your lock screen?

Comment: yes. Any notification. a text notification to be precise.

Comment: Do you get the broadcast when the screen is turned on?

Comment: Yes. See don't get confused with the push notification. this is a simple notification that occurs on status bar when we open the application and/or performing any action in the application would show the notification again. Can you help me with the lock screen part?

Comment: Do you want to show it in the status bar ?

Comment: No. on the screen. When the timer goes off, the pop up notification will appear in front of the lock screen.

Comment: Refer to [Showing a view using Window Manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015971/how-to-make-facebook-messenger-like-notification-like-this-in-android/20015985#20015985)

Comment: @Apoorv this doesn't work while the screen is locked.