# Android: How to draw free on top of anything (any activity)

Tags: java, android, view, android-activity

How do you draw a view on top of all other activities regardless of what they are showing and without using transparent activities or consuming its touch events.

Its like to display a custom icon on the screen on top of all other apps that reacts when you touch it but you can still touch the other views on the screen.

Example: facebook chat heads that displays a dragable and clickable icon on screen regardless of what you are doing whether you are on home screen or app menus or any app. Still you can click the chat head icon and background app elements seperately

How to do anything like that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Take a look at this cool article, I think that's exactly what you want :

http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics

In short : you want to add this permission to your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

For [api >= 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569937/unable-to-add-window-android-view-viewrootw44da9bc0-permission-denied-for-t#answer-34061521), you'll need to request the runtime permission `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION`

Then in a service, get the window manager

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
```

and add your views with the `addView` method

Comment: Exactly ! that's the answer I needed Thanks a TON mate!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/307923

Comment: This works for me on <23 devices, not on my 23 device. I'm targeting 22. Do I need to upgrade to 23+ and implement runtime permissions throughout to achieve this?

Comment: http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/   
your provided link is expired now, there is error Page not found :(, could you update if its relocation anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `WindowManager`. You can do something like `(WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService("window");` if you want to get the root view and use the method `addView(view, params)` if you want to add a view.

Comment: relevant but I needed more details ! thanks for your input anyway